# priority based data rows SQL optimization

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-optimization

Table **meas_point**:

- id
- name

Table **edge**:

- id
- name

Table **meas_point_data**:

- id
- meas_point_id (foreign key)
- date
- value

Table **edge_meas_point**:

- id
- edge_id (foreign key)
- meas_point_id (foreign key)
- order (int)

**Example Data**:

**meas_point**(id, name):

- 1, meas1
- 2, meas2
- 3, meas3

**edge**(id, name):

- 1, edge1

**edge_meas_point**(id, edge_id, meas_point_id, order):

- 1, 1, 1, 3
- 2, 1, 2, 1
- 3, 1, 3, 2

**meas_point_data**(id, meas_point_id, date, value):

- 1, 1, 2018-12-20, 11
- 2, 2, 2018-12-20, 12
- 3, 3, 2018-12-20, 13
- 4, 1, 2018-12-21, 21
- 5, 3, 2018-12-21, 23
- 6, 1, 2018-12-22, 31
- 7, 1, 2018-12-23, 41
- 8, 2, 2018-12-23, 42
- 9, 3, 2018-12-23, 43

**Idea**

Table edge_meas_point combines edge with meas_point at given priority(order). If there is no data from meas point at order 1, order 2 should be taken and so on. For example:

```
SELECT TOP 1 d.date, d.value
    FROM meas_point_data AS d, edge_meas_point AS em
    WHERE
      em.meas_point_id=d.meas_point_id AND
      em.edge_id=1 AND
      d.date=2018-12-21
    ORDER BY em.order
```

working great for one date in WHERE, but what if I want to draw a chart from that data ? Based on this example my select should return:

- 2018-12-20 - 12
- 2018-12-21 - 23
- 2018-12-22 - 31
- 2018-12-23 - 42

In my real scenario date is datetime - every 15 minutes. And i have to get data for last month ..this gives as (60/15) * 24 * 30 = 2880 points, and I have to draw few edges on one chart. So how to do this efficiently ? (I have to use MS SQL)

Comment: Start using ANSI JOIN syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you seem to want `GROUP BY` with some sort of "first" logic.  However, there is not a "first" aggregation function, so you can use the window function:

```
SELECT DISTINCT d.date,
       FIRST_VALUE(d.value) OVER (PARTITION BY d.date ORDER BY em.order)
FROM meas_point_data d JOIN
     edge_meas_point em 
     ON em.meas_point_id = d.meas_point_id
WHERE em.edge_id = 1;
```